# apt-get tries to install Popcorn Time

Tags: apt, software-installation

Whenever I run the `sudo apt-get install` command to install a program, the system also tries to install Popcorn Time. It takes like 5 minutes to give up. It's really frustrating when I'm installing a lot of stuff. How can I reconfigure the installation to avoid that?

[image]

I'm attaching an example of an installation:

[image: example image]

Comment: What's the exact command you ran? Please edit it into your question.

Comment: @wjandrea i didnt put the exact command, because it happens on every installation, sudo apt-get install "insert the package you want"

Comment: OK, then give an example.

Comment: @wjandrea ok, it's done